# How to delete file from local directory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been developing a java web app using spring n hibernate. This app can delete file from db, but I want this app can delete file from local directory too.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("remove")
public String remove(@ModelAttribute Xls file, HttpServletResponse response) {

    databaseService.remove(file);

    return "redirect:xlsFile";
}
```

and here is my DatabaseServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public void remove(Xls file) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(file);
    File file2 = new File("E:/webapps/xls/" /* + filename */);
    file2.delete();
}
```

and here is the picture to illustrate my case:
[image]

If somebody has experience for this, can you please share it here?
Any idea or help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Does the line `File file2 = new File("E:/webapps/xls/" + filename);` work correctly, or does it fail? Is `E:/webapps/xls/<filename>` the correct absolute path for the file in your local directory?

Comment: Where are you getting the commented out `filename` variable from? I think @Daemon is on the right track here - that path is possibly being built up incorrectly.

Comment: @Daemon, the line File file2 = new File("E:/webapps/xls/" + filename); should work correctly if the filename in db n in the absolute path is matched

Comment: @studro, in the snippet code above, the commented out filename variable is the name of existing file in my directory. my problem is how to get filename in db to match the filename in my directory?
can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried `File file2 = new File( "E:/webapps/xls/Sample.xls" );`? (ie. hardcoding the value?) Is the file deleted then? If so, there is something wrong with the way you're setting your `filename` variable. If not, you have a nastier problem with accessing the filesystem that I probably can't help with.